# Loading Japanese dictionary with UTF-8 through RMeCab / MeCab

Tags: r, dictionary, encoding, utf-8

I would like to ask if anyone has experience in encoding the Japanese dictionary data in MeCab into UTF-8. 
I have MeCab installed and the RMeCab package installed in R to make a wordmap in Japanese, but the POS tagging doesn't seem to work since the dictionary data is not encoded into UTF-8.

```
library("RMeCab")
library("wordcloud")
setwd('C:\\Users\\sukyu\\Desktop\\JP')
word <- RMeCabFreq("OLS_Japantext.txt")
word <- subset(word,Info1=="名詞")
type <- c("数","非自立","接尾")
word　<- subset(word,!Info2%in% type)
word <- word[order(word$Freq,decreasing =T ),]
pal <- brewer.pal(8,"Spectral")
par(family = "HiraKakuProN-W3")
wordcloud(word$Term,word$Freq,min.freq = 1,colors=pal,
      random.order = TRUE,scale = c(5,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

While by default it doesn't use UTF8, MeCab has a build option to force it. Try building it this way:

```
./configure --with-charset=utf8 --enable-utf8-only
```

That should fix it.